How to structure a reusable next.js component when using suspense and server actions?
Im new to Nextjs and I wonder how the things in the title mentioned fits together when a component has to be reused.
My understanding is:
A component that has an async function throws an error that indicates somehow to the next level boundary that it has a pending state. So the component can be wrapped into a React Suspense in order to catch and display that loading state.
That in reverse: A component in order to be displayed in loading state has to have it's data fetching inside a component instead of receiving fetched data through props.
My question:
How is a component supposed to be structured in order to be reusable while its displayable loading state requires the fetch method to be inside the component?
Talk in examples:
Let's talk about table components. We have filters, table header + body, and pagination
We can wrap these and initialise the components to make a custom table. A problem here is that the parent fetches the data that wraps these 3 components so its loading state would also replace the filters and pagination not just the body. To solve this data fetching should be in the table body.... then it is not so reusable anymore? In another scenario we pass down the server action as prop to the body to fetch data there... then we lose types.
This also needs some prop drilling to pass searchParams from the page to the table body.
Can someone point me to the right direction, please?
